# Кол-во просмотров вопроса в истории проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, нет-в-transifex

В [истории проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/109556) можно наблюдать несогласованную с числом форму для кол-ва просмотров вопроса:

> [image: 233 раз]

По результатам [общения в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33157862#33157862) было установлено, что данный блок не локализуется через transifex. Нужно его перевести на этот механизм или как-то иначе разрешить выставить правильную форму в зависимости от числа.